# How to colour the notification tray on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout, android-notification-bar

As you can see on the desing screen shot I have a tabLayout coloured in magenta. But the top notification gtray from the system is still black, where the antenna signal is. 
[image]

**Can I make the black notification tray in the same color I made the tabLayout?**

Comment: post your gradle and menifest & style.xml

Comment: change the color.... Colorprimarydark in your theme..... color match to antena color so no shown

Comment: The notification tray is not part of your app so I don't think so. You can make your app fullscreen to hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android **Lollipop** have ability to change the color of status bar in your app for a more immersive user experience and in tune with Google's Material Design Guidelines.

window.setStatusBarColor method introduced in **API level 21**

**Programatically**

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}`

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
       <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

[image]